# Faye websocket - 200 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, faye

I'm building an app that supports realtime bid using Faye-websocket. But I got this 200 error and I have no idea what problem it is.

Error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/auctions/3' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

SocketConnection.rb

```
require 'faye/websocket'
```

require 'websocket/extensions'
require 'thread'
require 'json'

class SocketConnection
    KEEPALIVE_TIME = 15 # in seconds

```
def initialize app 
    @app     = app 
end

def call env
    @env = env

    if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
        socket = Faye::WebSocket.new env

        socket.ping 'Mic check, one, two' do
          p [:ping, socket.object_id, socket.url]
        end

        socket.on :open do |event|
            p [:open, socket.object_id, socket.url]
            p [:open, socket.url, socket.version, socket.protocol]
        end

        socket.rack_response

    else
        @app.call(env)
    end
end
```

end

Comment: are you by chance trying this on a cloud dev environment? I ask because I had a similar issue on nitrous.io

Comment: no, i only work in local env. Did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I firgured out the problem. It requires a server to support socket connection. In my case, I use thin server. All errors are fixed